# Why this GROUP BY clause cause this error "42000Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column..."?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, rdbms

I am working on **MySql** database and I am implementing this query:

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                           AS livestock_species_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                    AS livestock_species_name_en,  
    LSN.livestock_species_name                      AS livestock_species_name,
    LSN.description                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                   AS image_link

FROM LivestockDetails                               AS LD
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies                         AS LS
      ON LD.live_stock_species_id = LS.id
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                     AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 3          

WHERE
     LD.ls_vaccination_id is not null
```

The previous query return the following result set:

```
livestock_species_id parent_livestock_species_id livestock_species_name_en                          livestock_species_name                             description image_link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
2                                                Chicken                                            Inkoko                                             Inkoko      https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fchicken.png?alt=media&token=badd0660-48ca-49f8-914a-8a9b8574a221                                                                            
2                                                Chicken                                            Inkoko                                             Inkoko      https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fchicken.png?alt=media&token=badd0660-48ca-49f8-914a-8a9b8574a221                                                                            
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
1                                                Cow                                                Inka                                               Inka        https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fcow.png?alt=media&token=c21866df-448a-4a72-9da2-d55d87f8b31c                                                                                
2                                                Chicken                                            Inkoko                                             Inkoko      https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fchicken.png?alt=media&token=badd0660-48ca-49f8-914a-8a9b8574a221                                                                            
2                                                Chicken                                            Inkoko                                             Inkoko      https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MY-PROJECT.appspot.com/o/img%2Ficons%2Flivestock%2Fchicken.png?alt=media&token=badd0660-48ca-49f8-914a-8a9b8574a221
```

As you can see the returned records are duplicated and I need to don't have these duplications.

So my idea was to use the **GROUP BY** clause.

My problem is that trying to do in this way (grouping by the **livestock_species_id** retrieved field):

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                           AS livestock_species_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                    AS livestock_species_name_en,  
    LSN.livestock_species_name                      AS livestock_species_name,
    LSN.description                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                   AS image_link

FROM LivestockDetails                               AS LD
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies                         AS LS
      ON LD.live_stock_species_id = LS.id
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                     AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 3          

WHERE
     LD.ls_vaccination_id is not null  

GROUP BY 
      livestock_species_id
```

MySql returning the following error message:

> 42000Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'digital_services_DB.LS.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this situation avoiding duplications?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: What do you expect this query to return?

Comment: @NicoHaase something like a single row having a common value of the livestock_species_id  field

Comment: What should it contain for all other columns?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Instead of just thinking "how do I suppress these duplicate rows", you ought to consider why you're getting duplicates. E.g. if there's some other column that does differ between the rows, is it correct that your join conditions don't filter down to select just one row per "group"? It's better to tighten up your conditions (in both joins and where) than to generate an exploded result-set and then stick a band-aid on by applying `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relating to my comment in re: preventing the duplicates from appearing in the first place - I'd guess that there are multiple rows in `LivestockDetails` that relate to the same species. And yet, in your query, you're not accessing any data from that table.

If you only want to report species for which you do have at least one row in `LivestockDetails`, use an `EXISTS` check instead:

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                           AS livestock_species_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                    AS livestock_species_name_en,  
    LSN.livestock_species_name                      AS livestock_species_name,
    LSN.description                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                   AS image_link

FROM LivestockSpecies                         AS LS
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                     AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 3          
WHERE
     EXISTS (SELECT * from LivestockDetails LD
             WHERE LD.live_stock_species_id = LS.id
             and LD.ls_vaccination_id is not null)
```

This should produce a better result (if the optimizer is doing a good job) because we don't generate the duplicates in the first place.

(If the correlated subquery for the exists check isn't working well, you may also want to experiment with:

```
SELECT
    LS.id                                           AS livestock_species_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                    AS livestock_species_name_en,  
    LSN.livestock_species_name                      AS livestock_species_name,
    LSN.description                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                   AS image_link

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT live_stock_species_id
      FROM LivestockDetails
      WHERE ls_vaccination_id is not null)          AS LD
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies                         AS LS
      ON LD.live_stock_species_id = LS.id
LEFT JOIN LivestockSpeciesName                     AS LSN
      ON LSN.livestock_species_id = LS.id AND LSN.language_id = 3
```

which at least stops the duplication as early as possible)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify all columns in the group by (or aggregate them). In your case, as you have duplicate records you can do it this way:

```
GROUP BY livestock_species_id,parent_livestock_species_id,
    livestock_species_name_en, livestock_species_name, 
    description,image_link
```

Or you can use distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LS.id                                           AS livestock_species_id,
    LS.parent_livestock_species_id                  AS parent_livestock_species_id,
    LS.livestock_species_name_en                    AS livestock_species_name_en,  
    LSN.livestock_species_name                      AS livestock_species_name,
    LSN.description                                 AS description,
    LS.image_link                                   AS image_link
```